# Prompting the user after an if statement in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, user-input

I'm new to C and trying to write a simple program. I ask the user to enter a month. I know how to check if it's a valid month, but unsure how to prompt the user to enter another if it ISNT a valid month. Here is what I came up with:
EDIT: updated code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int mon;

    do {
        printf("Enter a month(1=Jan, ..., 12=Dec: ");
        scanf("%d", &mon);
    } while (mon < 1 || mon > 12);
        printf("Not a valid month.");
}
```

But now my while-block is only getting printed if I enter a number between 1-12. If I enter an invalid month I am still prompted to enter another, but the program terminates if I enter a correct number.

Comment: Read the chapter about loops in your programming book.

Comment: Could be solved using the `while` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can use do-while loop as follows:

```
int mon;
do{
    printf("Enter a month(1=Jan, ..., 12=Dec): \n");
    scanf("%d", &mon);
} while(mon < 1 || mon > 12);
```

It will continue, if the input is correct and loop again when false input.

Based on your updated code, you will print the message when the users input is valid.

You probably wanted something like this:

```
for (;;)//infinite loop (no condition)
{
    printf("Enter a month(1=Jan, ..., 12=Dec): ");
    scanf("%d", &mon);

    if (mon < 12 && mon > 0)    // if inside the range (1-12) then break the loop and continue
        break;
    else // otherwise show the error message and repeat again
        printf("Error message \n");
}
```

Comment: Will try using 'while' now. Can you explain why you chose to put the print statements in a do-block?

Comment: @flarp because do block will execute once even if the condition is false; it exetuce do block first, then it will check the condition... Otherwise it is the same as while loop

Comment: @Quest I tried to do-block like you said and made my while-block printf("not a valid month.")
When I enter numbers > 12 and <1 the print statement doesnt come up, but when I do a number between 1-12 it does, which seems backwards according to my code. Any suggestions?

Comment: @flarp please post the code.. otherwise I can't help you much.

Comment: @flarp  `stdout` is buffered.  It printed at the end of the program.  Add `'\n'` and/or `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf()` to force immediate output.

Comment: @Quest just updated the original post. Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` is not friendly to bad input.  I would suggest using `fgets()` and then parse.

```
int main(void) {
  int mon;
  for (;;) {
    char buf[100];
    printf("Enter a month(1=Jan, ..., 12=Dec): ");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) 
      return 1;  // no more input
    if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &mon) == 1 && mon >= 1 && mon <= 12) {
      break;  // Success!
    }
    printf("Not a valid month ");
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

Additional testing could to used to detect overflow or data after the integer.

Answer (score 0):

If you like kind of oneliners, here it is:

```
while(printf("Enter Month\n") && scanf("%d",&mon) && (mon < 1 || mon > 12));
```

**code:**

```
main()
{
    int mon;
    while(printf("Enter Month\n") && scanf("%d",&mon) && (mon < 1 || mon > 12));
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./a.out 
Enter Month
0
Enter Month
99
Enter Month
98
Enter Month
44
Enter Month
13
Enter Month
12
$
```

Comment: One linear code like this is: 1) very difficult to read 2) hard to maintain. You should write code not for yourself, but for others to be easy readable. Just remember those poor guys who will have to read such one linears...

Comment: @Quest: I completely agree with you!!, thats why, I wrote **If you like kind of oneliners**

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int month, condition = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("enter month");
        scanf("%d", &month);
        if (month < 1 || month>12)
            condition = 1;
        else
            condition = 0;
    } while (condition == 1);
    return 0;
}
```